Firestore JSON parsing terminated
I tried many ways to fix it , but i couldn't .
JSON :
jsonData := '{"select": {"fields": [{"fieldPath": "name1"}]}, "from": [{"collectionId": "collec"}], "where": {"fieldFilter": {"field": {"fieldPath": "name2"}, "op": "EQUAL", "value": {"stringValue": "mac"}}}}}'

error :

invalid JSON payload received , parsing terminated before end of input.

It refers to:
{"stringValue": "mac"}
                 ^

even a JSON formatter tells its correct
I saw firebase doc and i didn't find any solution

According to https://jsonlint.com/ there is one too many } at the end of your string.

There's an extra trailing } at the end. Remove that and the JSON will then resolve to:
{
  "select": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldPath": "name1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "from": [
    {
      "collectionId": "collec"
    }
  ],
  "where": {
    "fieldFilter": {
      "field": {
        "fieldPath": "name2"
      },
      "op": "EQUAL",
      "value": {
        "stringValue": "mac"
      }
    }
  }
}

